Request Permission Prompt not showing to user android
I have a simple app that has just 1 button in the activity and this is my MainActivity.kt file code:
    package ir.alirezapersonal.startup2
    
    import android.Manifest
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager
    import android.os.Build
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.util.Log
    import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
    import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
    import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
    import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
    import ir.alirezapersonal.startup2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        binding.btnRequestPermissions.setOnClickListener {
            requestPermissions()
        }
    }

    private fun hasWriteExternalStoragePermission() =
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    private fun hasLocationForegroundPermission() =
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    private fun hasLocationBackgroundPermission() =
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        var permissionsToRequest = mutableListOf<String>()
        if(!hasWriteExternalStoragePermission()){
            permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }
        if(!hasLocationForegroundPermission()){
            permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        }
        if (!hasLocationBackgroundPermission()){
            permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
        }

        if(permissionsToRequest.isNotEmpty()){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsToRequest.toTypedArray(),0)
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode == 0 && grantResults.isNotEmpty()){
            for(i in grantResults.indices){
                if(grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Log.d("PermissionRequest", "${permissions[i]} granted.")
                } else {
                    Log.d("PermissionRequest", "${permissions[i]} NOT granted.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

the problem is that when i click on the button the permission request is not prompted to the user. i have also addded permissions list in my manifest file:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Startup2"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

i am also tested this app on an android 13 and 14 device but didn't solve the problem.
what could be the problem?

I assume that you have never rejected the permission and this is the first time asking for them?

@tyczj yes never rejected them

try removing the write external storage permission from the list you are trying to ask for when you launch the permission flow

Also the Access background location isnt a permission you need to ask for in that list either

@tyczj i removed the external storage permission and it worked thanks earlier in the code i tried to debug and got something like: '''''' ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsToRequest.toTypedArray(),0) = unspecified ''''''' but i didn't know that this permission is not supported in newer versions of android

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

If your app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.R or higher, this permission has no effect.
If your app is on a device that runs API level 19 or higher, you don't need to declare this permission to read and write files in your application-specific directories returned by Context.getExternalFilesDir(String) and Context.getExternalCacheDir().

ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

Allows an app to access location in the background. If you're requesting this permission, you must also request either ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. Requesting this permission by itself doesn't give you location access.

You do not need both location permissions https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/permissions#types-of-access

@tyczj I've corrected my answer. Thank you.
